# How to enable a button only when a checkbox is checked or unchecked after form load?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have some functions and which i want is to enable a button when any of the state of checkbox will be changed but only after the form load i mean when someone do it manually i have some check and uncheck boxes on my list view

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.Columns.Add("A Name", 180);
        listView1.Columns.Add("B", 260);
        listView1.Columns.Add("C", 80);
        listView1.Columns.Add("D", 100);
        ListPrograms();


        foreach(ListViewItem theItem in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (theItem.Checked == true)
            {
                theItem.ForeColor = Color.White;


            }
        }

        //CreateMyListView();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem l = listView1.Items[e.Index];

        //Display message
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(l.Text + " was just checked.");
            button1.Enabled = true;

        }


        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(l.Text + " was just unchecked.");
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After initialization we have to call all the functions that we need then we have to add this form load..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a bool if the loading process has finished yet and only do something, if that value is true

```
bool loadingDone = false;
```

At the end of your Form_Load(), write

```
loadingDone = true;
```

In your checkbox change event, write

```
if (loadingDone) { DoSomething() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Enabled or Change the Back Color Of the button..

like this.

```
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```